# Why won't google accept my Sitemap.xml? "URL not allowed This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location."

Tags: asp.net, sitemap.xml

I have a google custom search pointing at `http://xxx/edu_dir_new/*` .  I am trying to upload a Sitemap.xml (right now, with just one page)

Sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://xxx/edu_dir_new/DOEEmployee/i3/JanetRay/Directory.aspx</loc>
    </url>
 </urlset>
```

The path (edu_dir_new/DOEEmployee/i3/JanetRay/Directory.aspx) is not an actual set of directories, but does serve up a page (by implementing an alternate IHttpModule).

It is unlikely that this site is linked to anywhere else on the web, (because it's in test), but from what I can tell, this shouldn't matter if I specify a sitemap.

Comment: At one place you say "ed_dir_new" at another "edu_dir_new" is that correct?

Comment: I saw that- error in the post, not in the google search or sitemap.  Fixed, thx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That error usually means that you have an URL pointing to a different Domain from yours. When you tell google to retrieve the sitemap.xml file, are you using an URL pointing to the same machine? (xxx in your example).

Also, as I guess that you are using Google Webmaster Tools, check that 'xxx' is the name of the server you are configuring. Something silly as omitting the 'www', using the IP address, or simply mistyping a letter could be the cause of the error.

I don't know if google checks it, but if the address actually returns a 3xx http redirect response, it could also refuse the url (if the redirection points to a different domain)

Comment: Got it, thanks!   The url for the site and the pages in the sitemap appear to have to match case sensitively..